# Spring boot test with @DirtiesContext BEFORE_CLASS

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot

Hello I recently updated my spring boot application and noticed new feature ( DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS), that seems fit my needs, because I had the problem with reloading bean with method annotated @RabbitListener, for some reason Spring reloaded that bean, but old bean was using as rabbit listener. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994273/rabbitlistener-method-testing-in-springboot-app))

My code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes ={ServerConfig.class,ServerThroughAMQPBrokerRabbitMQIntegrationTestConfig.class})
@Category({IntegrationTest.class})
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
public class ServerThroughAMQPBrokerRabbitMQIntegrationTest {
```

The issue that,after adding DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS Spring stops loading beans from:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes ={ServerConfig.class,ServerThroughAMQPBrokerRabbitMQIntegrationTestConfig.class})
```

So the questions:

How should I load spring context with DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS ?

Comment: I would like to know this as well, since I'm having a similar issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution here is to add [DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/test/context/support/DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.html) to list of your `@TestExecutionListeners`, which will provide support for dependency injection.

> TestExecutionListener which provides support for dependency injection
>   and initialization of test instances.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes ={ServerConfig.class,ServerThroughAMQPBrokerRabbitMQIntegrationTestConfig.class})
@Category({IntegrationTest.class})
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
public class ServerThroughAMQPBrokerRabbitMQIntegrationTest {
```

This is from DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener javadoc

> When merging TestExecutionListeners with the defaults, this listener
>   will automatically be ordered before the
>   DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener; otherwise, this listener
>   must be manually configured to execute before the
>   DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.

Also you could remove `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation on your test class. If no such annotation is present Spring will inject the default listener which will include `DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener.class` and `DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class`

Here is the list of default listeners without `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation for SpringBoot application

[image]